# Having trouble parsing response data in my NextJS API routes, keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, rest, request, next.js, response

I'm trying return the dummy data of a REST API I'm setting up in NextJS, but It keeps returning undefined. I've been stuck here for a long time and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
export default function userHandler(req, res) {
  const {
    query: { id, name },
    method,
  } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      res.status(200).json({ id, name: `User ${id} ${name}` });
      console.log(`${req.name}`);
      break;
    case "PUT":
      res.status(200).json({ id, name: name || `User ${id}` });
      break;
    default:
      res.setHeader("Allow", ["GET", "PUT"]);
      res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`);
  }
}
```

my localhost:3000/user/1 returns "User 1 undefined" and my console.log also returns undefined.

How can I get "undefined" return the actual value?
Ive tried Json.stringify, and JSON.parse.

Comment: What is the logging output of JSON.stringify(req.query)?

Comment: it outputs `{"id":"1"}`

Comment: Could you please include your rest api definition, where this userHandler is being used?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/EricPezzulo/9d8a5017200ff99ad11326a4e7ee0eb2

Comment: There is no logic written to get the complete user object from the user-id.  You need to write some logic that uses the passed user id to find the correct user object from the users array defined in (pages/api/users.js). Then use that user object to get user name.

Comment: "How can I get "undefined" return the actual value?" - Return the actual value from where? Your API route is simply returning what it's getting passed in the query params.